# pe:inputNumber value return null

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, xhtml, primefaces-extensions

I have this **p:dataTable**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"> 
<h:form id="form" prependId="false">
    <p:dataTable var="row" id="list" value="#{BB.dataTable}" rowIndexVar="i">
        <p:column headerText="#{bundle['id']}">
            <h:outputText value="#{row.id}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:columns var="fecha" value="#{BB.lFechaEntradaVigor}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{fecha}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{row.getCoste(fecha)}" styleClass="#{row.isValido(fecha)?'vigor':''}" rendered="#{!row.isUpdatable(fecha)}">
                <f:convertNumber groupingUsed="true" minFractionDigits="2" />
            </h:outputText>
            <pe:inputNumber value="#{BB.valor}" rendered="#{row.isUpdatable(fecha)}" >
                <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{BB.changeValor(fecha, row, i)}" />
            </pe:inputNumber>
        </p:columns>
    </p:dataTable>
    <p:commandButton value="#{bundleComunes.guardar}" action="#{BB.saveData()}" />
</h:form>
```

When I call `changeValor` `valor` always return **null**, but when I write `pe:inputNumber` out of `p:columns` works.
Any idea???

Comment: `<h:outputText value="#{row.d}" />` in row.d you must create getter setter for d object.

Comment: My problem are with imputNumber inside p:columns, not with `row.id` before `row.d`

Comment: can you post all your root elements of document. I mean `xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding one backing bean attribute to many input fields seems weird to me. Try passing the component value as an argument to changeValor():

```
<pe:inputNumber value="#{BB.valor}" rendered="#{row.isUpdatable(fecha)}" >
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{BB.changeValor(component.value, fecha, row, i)}" />
</pe:inputNumber>
```

Or better yet use a remote command. Place the following outside your table:

```
<pe:remoteCommand name="changeValor" 
    process="@this" 
    actionListener="#{BB.changeValor}" 
    global="false" 
    partialSubmit="true">
    <pe:methodSignature parameters="java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String" />
    <pe:methodParam name="valor" />
    <pe:methodParam name="fecha" />
    <pe:methodParam name="row" />
    <pe:methodParam name="i" />
</pe:remoteCommand>
```

Don't forget to corrent the parameter types.

Now the markup for the inputNumber:

```
<pe:inputNumber value="#{BB.valor}" rendered="#{row.isUpdatable(fecha)}"  onchange="changeValor(this.value, #{fecha}, #{row}, #{i})" />
</pe:inputNumber>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do like this :

```
   <pe:inputNumber value="#{BB.valor}"
decimalSeparator="," decimalPlaces="2" thousandSeparator="." emptyValue="0"
id="id1" style="width:100px" />
```

Comment: same problem, not send `valor`

Comment: if it doesn't work maybe you hame some problem in your manage bean , or any bean that you use

Comment: I don´t think so, because when I use `pe:inputNumber` out of `p:columns` works

Answer (score 0):

the solution is for example

```
  <p:inputNumber id="haberNumber" value="#{diarioController.haber}" >
                        <p:ajax update="haberNumber" />
</p:inputNumber>
```

work fine!!!

Answer (score -2):

```
<pe:inputNumber autocomplete="off" ... />
```